# How to add NamedQueries annotation with hyperjaxb

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, named-query, hyperjaxb

My question is very simple and straightforward. I need to add a @NamedQueries annotation to my generated entity classes. The JPA layer is being generated with Hyperjaxb. I do not know how to use the  element to add this line

```
...
@NamedQueries(value = {
    @NamedQuery(name ="SampleType.sampleQuery", query="select r from SampleType r where r.index=:index"),
})
public class SampleType{
....
}
```

How do I add that specific annotation to the generated type?

```
<bindings node="xsd:complexType[@name='SampleType']">
.... // What do I put here???
</bindings>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out

```
<bindings node="xsd:complexType[@name='SampleType']">
<annox:annotate>
    <annox:annotate
        annox:class="org.hibernate.annotations.NamedQueries">
        <annox:annotate
            annox:class="org.hibernate.annotations.NamedQuery"
            name="SampleType.sampleQuery" query="select r from SampleType r where r.index=:index">
        </annox:annotate>
    </annox:annotate>
</annox:annotate> 
....
....
</bindings>
```

Comment: This is the correct solution. In recent version you can define your annotations in Java syntax (see [this](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin#providing-annotations)), just use fully qualified class names. This is easier than XML format.

Comment: That's great! Defining annotations directly in Java syntax makes it more readable.